# Typo3 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module

Tags: javascript, typo3-8.x

The error occures when I start my extension in TYPO3(Version: 8.7.19) or when I click on any button inside my view. I'm not sure what to do or try at this point after trying different solutions.

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () {
return a("list.js")
}
at makeError (require.js:1)
at r (require.js:1)
at require.js:1
```

Hint:

> Be sure to load all scripts that call define() via the RequireJS API. Do not manually code script tags in HTML to load scripts that have define() calls in them.

Following this hint I serached in my extension for all .js files using the call define(). and found 1.

FormEngine.js uses this call

```
define('TYPO3/CMS/Backend/FormEngine', ['jquery'], function ($) {
...
}
```

and is included like this in Default.html

```
<script src="{f:uri.resource(path:'js/FormEngine.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I tried the following solution which I'm guessing would be working but I'm not able to find the requirejs.config. 
Normally I would search for this in the app.js but app.js and require.js are in the TYPO3 Core where i unlikely want to make a change.

https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles

Thanks in advance.